# Etymology of 鞄 (かばん)

Tags: etymology

I recently learned of the Korean word 가방 (*gaban*), which is supposedly derived from 鞄 (かばん), but it seems there isn't much of a solid trail after that.

From what I can tell, it might be related to the Chinese *jiābǎn*, though under the Korean entry for [가방](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B0%80%EB%B0%A9#Korean), there's mention of the Dutch *kabas*.

Wiktionary is too brief to be decisive here. Do we have a good guess as to the etymology of かばん, and is it related to the Korean 가방, the Dutch *kabas*, or the Chinese *jiābǎn*?

Comment: I found a website that seeking the etymology of かばん (and origin of the letter 鞄 as かばん) but it doesn’t seem to have found anything convincing... https://japanbag.com/

Comment: @rk03 But the interesting thing to note there is that it isn't attested before the Meiji period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wiktionary is too brief to be decisive here.

I'm an admin over there, and helped work on the [Japanese entry for 鞄](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9E%84#Japanese).  We seldom get the chance to talk with users directly about the site, so I'm keen to find out from you  -- what kind of expansion of the etymology there would be helpful to you?  If you're open to longer discussion than a one-off comment below, please do so [on my Wiktionary talk page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Eirikr), since this particular topic is outside scope for the Japanese Stack Exchange.

> Do we have a good guess as to the etymology of かばん, and is it related to the Korean 가방 (*kabang*)...

I'm not fluent in Korean, but what I can glean about 가방 is that it was a borrowing from Japanese.  See also the [Korean Wikipedia article](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B0%80%EB%B0%A9), or [this page on Namu.wiki](https://namu.wiki/w/%EA%B0%80%EB%B0%A9#%EC%96%B4%EC%9B%90).

> ...[is かばん related to] the Dutch *kabas*...

From the Namu.wiki page, it seems like the National Institute of the Korean Language views Dutch *kabas* as the origin of the Japanese term, and a few posts on the Korean "Naver" site (like [this one](https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.naver?isHttpsRedirect=true&blogId=lafi21&logNo=220244569593)) follow suit.  The Japanese-language [Daijisen entry on Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%9E%84-465636#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) also mentions the Dutch term *kabas* as another possibility.

However, this theory is problematic in multiple ways.

- The Dutch word is more specifically Belgian Flemish ([1](https://www.woorden.org/woord/kabas), [2](https://gtb.ivdnt.org/iWDB/search?actie=article&wdb=WNT&id=M029363&lemmodern=kabas&Betekenis_id=M029363.bet.1)), apparently.  Some mainstream monolingual Dutch dictionaries don't even include the word, like the [*Algemeen Nederlands Woordenboek*](https://anw.ivdnt.org/search?type=simple&q=kabas).
- The main meaning of the term seems to be "basket", in keeping with its [derivation](https://gtb.ivdnt.org/iWDB/search?actie=article&wdb=WNT&id=M029363&lemmodern=kabas&Betekenis_id=M029363.bet.1) in turn from Middle French [*cabas*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cabas#French) of similar sense.  This doesn't overlap well with the Japanese term's attested meaning of "satchel", nor the kanji 鞄's earlier sense of "worked leather; leather bag".
- The phonology is decidedly off -- that final //s// in the Dutch has no correlation with the final //ɴ// in the Japanese.
- The Japanese term 鞄 with the reading *kaban* and a meaning of "bag, satchel" isn't attested until 1877.  This makes the semantic (meaning) and phonological (sound) changes required to go from Flemish *kabas* ("basket") to Japanese *kabaɴ* ("satchel") even less likely.

→ Ultimately, I think the Flemish term is an accidental kinda-sorta resemblance, and not at all related.  It's actually surprisingly easy to find words in any two languages that kinda sorta sound similar and kinda sorta have similar meanings -- and this gets even easier if you aren't that picky about the sounds and the meanings lining up all that closely, as with *kabas* ("basket") and *kabaɴ* ("satchel").  If you're interested in word origins and comparative linguistics, I highly recommend you read ["How likely are chance resemblances between languages?"](https://www.zompist.com/chance.htm)  The author even lays out a well-backed-up mathematical model for determining the likelihood of such non-cognate similarities.  See also [this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73488/5229) exploring any possible connection between English *name* and Japanese 名前 (*namae*).

> ... or [is かばん related to] the Chinese *jiābǎn*?

Per the references cited in the Wiktionary entry (Daijirin [no free online version I'm aware of], NKD [available via Kotobank [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%9E%84-465636)], Encyclopedia Nipponica [entry [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%9E%84-465636#E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.A4.A7.E7.99.BE.E7.A7.91.E5.85.A8.E6.9B.B8.28.E3.83.8B.E3.83.83.E3.83.9D.E3.83.8B.E3.82.AB.29), also on Kotobank]) and [Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%9E%84-465636#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) (not yet included in the Wiktionary entry's references), the connection with Chinese 夹板 or 夾槾 keeps getting referenced as the likely source.

- Phonologically, this makes some sense, considering the Japanese references' indicated reading of きゃばん and the pronunciation of Chinese languages like Min Nan's *kiap-pán*.  A shift from きゃばん to かばん is much easier to explain as a change from palatal glide //ja// to //a//, a monophthongization.  I notice too that [apparently](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%BE#Chinese) another Min Nan pronunciation for the 夾 character is *kap*.
- Semantically, the Japanese resources describe the Chinese term as purportedly meaning something like "pressing together + board" in reference to a container or holder for documents, essentially a kind of briefcase (two flat stiff boards used to sandwich documents and keep them flat), which is also a closer match than the Flemish word for "basket".

→ In conclusion, while not definite (as the [Nipponica entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%9E%84-465636#E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.A4.A7.E7.99.BE.E7.A7.91.E5.85.A8.E6.9B.B8.28.E3.83.8B.E3.83.83.E3.83.9D.E3.83.8B.E3.82.AB.29) itself calls out: 「語源【ごげん】はかならずしも明確【めいかく】でないが...」, "the etymology is not entirely clear, but..."), the Chinese derivation seems the most likely.

Comment: I believe even in Mandarin what is now written with /j/ in pinyin was pronounced like /g/ (and /q/ like /k/ with aspiration) until like the 19th century as we can see in the old transliteration of Peking.

Comment: Has かばん ever been *spelt* as 夹板 in Japanese? That would be a litmus test that I think needs to be passed for the Chinese-etymology claim, unless the word was transmitted through a time/location of an oral-only Chinese variety. Maybe Minnan would make sense in that case (southern coastal traders?)

Comment: @dROOOze, so far as I've found to date, the word _kaban_ in Japanese isn't attested until 1877, and then already with the kanji spelling 鞄.  My reading of the NKD entry's wording of 『明治期【めいじき】に「かばん」の読【よ】みをあてた』 is that this kanji previously had no such _kun'yomi_. There is an older Japanese word [挟板](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%8C%9F%E6%9D%BF-1301679), attested since 1603 with a meaning of "boards for sandwiching cloth or other material" and a reading of _hasami ita_. For _kaban_ though, the only word I can find is 鞄.

Answer (score 2):

Is the desire to know the etymology due to the sound of the word or how the Kanji is written?

If it's the Kanji, looking at its parts may give more understanding.
革 or 'kawa' is leather and 包 or 'kurumu/tsutsumu' is (a) wrap.

If the origin of the sound (phoneme?) is what you seek, I believe Eiríkr Útlendi's explaination of the Min Nan pronunciation makes the most sense. (I really couldn't add anything to it.)